# sic with last word

Tags: punctuation

When one purposefully spells the last words in a sentence wrong, would the end punctuation be before or after the bracket?  Ex.: The pizza is there's [sic]. or The pizza is there's. [sic]

Comment: [Here's a written example](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22leave+to+theirs+%5Bsic%5D%22) where *[sic]* is used twice in one sentence: **Dr. Thurston has spoke [sic] to parents; Runis staff need to clarify with Kai's parents if they are happy for Kai to have escorted leave to theirs [sic].** That looks fine to me, given the general idea is to put *[sic]* as close as possible to the "questionable" text (so why would you want to include the period *before* the "confirmation"?).

Answer (score 1):

Customarily *sic* is put [as close as possible following the error](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/sic/). That would suggest putting it before the punctuation.

Besides this, style guides are either silent on the topic or employ examples putting punctuation marks after the *sic*. Expert editor Merrill Perlman [shares an example](https://archives.cjr.org/language_corner/language_corner_080914.php) where punctuation is used after the *sic*:

> “I’ve spent a lot of my life thinking blackness was all I had in front of me, that it would be blackness to the very last instent[sic],” he wrote in a journal, according to the Post.

Note how [MLA 8 usage](https://sites.psu.edu/bee11/files/2010/07/MLA-8th-Edition-Quick-Reference-August-2016-17iiok3.pdf) can vary based on whether the text appears within or after the quotation marks. In either case, *sic* appears before the punctuation:

> Shaw admitted, “Nothing can extinguish my interest in Shakespear” (sic).

And in [this curious document](http://www.mtcra.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/SIC-RULES.pdf) collected by Marla Sharp under the domain for the Montana Court Reporters Association, examples always have *sic* appear before the punctuation.

Comment: I would say that the [sic] is attached to the uncorrected error and that the whole thing thus created must precede any punctuation that was intended to follow the erroneous matter.